# Dynamically use React Component based on data in an object

Tags: reactjs, vite

I'm creating this menu as a fun project in React, and I've finished the code to display/style the components, so now I'm setting it up to be dynamic and generate the menu based on a passed set of data. My React project routes like this:`App /`→`Tab /`→Various components based on data.

The plan is to have a menu (`App/`) contain potentially multiple `Tab /` of various inputs, such as date, text, number, range, etc. Let's say I use this dataset as an example:

```js
elements: [
  {
    type: 'number',
    text: 'Some Text Label',
    fields: [
      {
        text: 'Some Text',
        min: 0,
        max: 50,
        value: 25,
      },
      {
        text: 'Some Text',
        min: 25,
        max: 75,
        value: 50,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    type: 'text',
    text: 'Some Text Label',
    fields: [
      {
        text: 'Some Text',
        value: 'Some Text Placeholder',
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    type: 'number',
    text: 'Some Text Label',
    fields: [
      {
        text: 'Some Text',
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        value: 50,
      },
    ],
  },
]
```

Within the `Tab /` component, I'd want to look through the elements to find the type of one element, then use the component that is ready for that element (for example, type:`number`, I would use `Number /` and then pass the fields as a prop to that component.

> Something like this:`Number fields={insertdatahere}/>`

I'm a total beginner when it comes to react, but I've tried a few ways myself and I feel like I'm just missing something because nothing is working. I was considering just having all the Components manually placed inside the tab component and having them set as `Display: None` unless an element is present for that type. Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a [Code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-pond-ke1vyv?file=/src/App.js) which illustrates one way you could get started.

The basic idea is to define a component for each type of field (text, number, ...) and make a lookup. A function component is like any other value in Javascript - you can store it in an array or an object.

In this case I've defined `TextDisplay` and `NumberDisplay`:

```js
const TextDisplay = ({ text, value }) => (
  <li>
    <h4>{text}</h4>
    <input value={value} />
  </li>
);

const NumberDisplay = ({ text, min, max, value }) => (
  <div>
    <h4>{text}</h4>
    <input type="number" min={min} max={max} value={value} />
  </div>
);

const ComponentForType = {
  text: TextDisplay,
  number: NumberDisplay
};
```

Then there's a bit of machinery for displaying the lists of elements in the definition, and the list of fields in each element.

Hopefully that can give you something to play around with. There's a bit of weird syntax in there like the spread operator, and everything gets complicated once you want to make the values editable, but this could be a starting point.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, so I think where I'm going wrong here is I have all of my components setup in separate .jsx files. For example I have "Tab.jsx" and I use 
```
import { Checkbox, Date, LongText, ShortText, Slider, Number } from '../index';
```
in order to import the external components and use them within the menu Tab component.

Is it possible in this way, or should I move to create all of the components for each element type, inside of the Tab.jsx file

Comment: You can keep them in other files, import them, and then list them in the component lookup. They are just plain old Javascript values.

Comment: Yeah, I ended up doing this, thanks for steering me in the right direction. I've got it all working so far :)